# Xamarin - SQLite Join

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, cross-platform

Estou criando um app no xamarin, que gera um pedido de venda, e armazena no celular.

Estou utilizando o SQLite pra armazenar os dados, mas eu estou com problema pra fazer um join entre a minha tabela de Itens do pedido, e a tabela de Produtos.

Eu tenho os dois modelos abaixo:

```
[Table("tbPROD")]
public class PROD
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int PROD_Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string PROD_Descricao { get; set; }

    public decimal PROD_Preco { get; set; }
}

[Table("tbITPD")]
public class ITPD
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ITPD_Id { get; set; }

    public int ITPD_PEDI_Id { get; set; }

    public int ITPD_PROD_Id { get; set; }

    public int ITPD_Quantidade { get; set; }

    public decimal ITPD_ValorTotal { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", ITPD_Id, ITPD_PROD_Id, ITPD_Quantidade, ITPD_ValorTotal);
    }
}
```

Eu precisava fazer um select no ITPD pegando a descrição do produto, no caso inner join tbPROD on PROD_Id = ITPD_PROD_Id. Mas no SQLite não estou conseguindo fazer isso, outra coisa também, eu consigo fazer montar select no SQLite? Tipo, "select PROD_Id, PROD_Descricao from tbPROD".

Estou perguntando isso, porque os selects que estou utilizando, esta da seguinte forma:

```
public List<PROD> GetProdutos(string valor)
    {
        List<PROD> list = new List<PROD>();

        try
        {
            list = valor == string.Empty ?
                _SQLiteConnection.Table<PROD>()
                                 .OrderBy(p => p.PROD_Id)
                                 .ToList() :
                _SQLiteConnection.Table<PROD>()
                                 .Where(p => p.PROD_Descricao.Contains(valor))
                                 .OrderBy(p => p.PROD_Id)
                                 .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HasError = true;
            MsgError = ex.Message;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

---

@Randrade, não consegui seguir com o link que você me passou, na verdade, eu não estou conseguindo entender como funciona.

Alguem poderia fazer um exemplo pra mim, com essas duas classes minha?

Segue abaixo:

CLIE (Clientes):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PEDI (Pedidos)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o select:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o campo PEDI_CLIE_Descricao na classe PEDI, meu select funciona corretamente! Mas como que ficaria, se eu tirasse esse campo? Como ficaria a modelagem e o select?

Answer (score 1):

O SQLite não suporta `.Join` via `linq` naturalmente. O que você pode fazer é fazer a consulta na mão.

```
_SQLiteConnection.Query<PROD>(
        "select * from tbPROD p INNER JOIN tbITPD pd on p.PROD_Id = pd.ITPD_PROD_id").ToList();
```

Mais detalhes pode ser visto na [documentação oficial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/).

Agora, caso queira usar uma biblioteca de terceiros, existe a [SQLite .Net Extensions](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions), que permite utilizar o `.Join` via `linq`.

Comment: A sim, entendi!

Mas no Query<PROD>, não posso colocar minha classe PROD ali, porque vai retornar campos da classe ITPD e da PROD, ai não funcionaria. Eu baixei essa extensão, mas não consegui usar direito não haha

Vou fazer mais uns testes, pra ver o que consigo fazer, valeu!

Comment: @felipedrt Eu coloquei ali apenas como exemplo. Você deve colocar a classe correta.

Comment: Então, esse é o problema! Não tem a classe correta, estou tentando utilizar o dynamic, pra ver se consigo fazer alguma coisa.

Comment: @felipedrt Da forma que eu coloquei, você está trabalhando com dados dinâmicos. O `Xamarin` faz essa conversão automaticamente. Mas se você não tem uma classe para colocar na consulta, tem algo muito errado com a sua modelagem.

Comment: Então, na verdade é isso que está acontecendo, tem coisa errada na modelagem mesmo. O que eu deveria fazer, criar uma classe, com os dados que serão retornados? Ou colocar os campos na classe ITPD?

Preciso retornar esses campos no meu select -> Id do item, Id do pedido, Descricao do produto, Valor do produto, Quantidade, Valor total;

Descrição do produto, e valor, estão na classe PROD, os outros campos estão na classe ITPD..

Comment: @felipedrt Você não precisa criar uma classe nova, precisa apenas fazer uma modelagem correta, utilizando `OneToOne` ou `OneToMany`, dependendo do seu contexto. [Olhe esse exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29005182/4843158), acho que lhe ajudará.

Comment: Beleza, vou ver se consigo modelar certinho aqui, valeu!